# How to sum attributes of a Eigen vector of class

Tags: c++, eigen

I have declared a vector of a class I created like this:

```
typedef Eigen::Vector<Trade, Dynamic> VectorT;
```

And I am trying to sum a rolling window of trade.amount

Before switching from `std::vector` to `Eigen::Vector` I did this

```
for (size_t i = 30; i < trades.size(); ++i) {
    double cum_buy_qty = 0;
    for (size_t k = i - 30; k <= i; ++k) {
        cum_buy_qty += trades[k].buyQuantity;
}}
```

Now I am slicing the vector like that:

```
for (size_t i = 30; i < trades.rows(); ++i) {
    VectorT slice = trades(seq(i - 30, i));
}
```

But I don't know I could sum the attribute `buyQuantity` for each `Trade` in my new slice `vector`.

Any idea please?